# How can I merge a module in an instance?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to like merge or add some methods and attributes of a module in a class.

```
function User(data){
  this.name = data.name;
}

User.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  return this.name+' says hello.';
}

module.exports = User;
```

I would like  to add to my User some attributes and methods from a Player class once it has joined a game for exemple.

```
function Player(user){
  this.chances = 3;
}

Player.prototype.run = function(){
 return this.name+' is running.';
}
```

I tried with a subClass but I loose all the parameters from User and have only the Player's one. I would like to do something like this :

```
var user = new User({name:Jacques});

user.sayHello() // Jacques says hello.

user.becomePlayer();

user.run(); // Jacques is running.
```

Or is it possible to add attributes and methods to the user variable ?

```
user.becomePlayer() // user now can run.
```

Comment: If the classes don't inherit from each other, an object cannot be an instance of both.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a method on the object user,you can do sth like this:

```
User.prototype =  {
    sayHello : function(){
        return this.name+' says hello.';
    },
    becomePlayer: function () {
        //do some thing
    }
}
```

if user want to access the player's method, you can use inheritance(
Prototype chain inheritance)：

```
User.prototype = new Player();
var user = new User({name: 'Jacques'})

console.log(user.run());//Jacques is running.
```

Comment: Thank you, but what If I only want the Player attributes and methods to be part of the User instance just by using the becomePlayer method of the User instance. Like an evolution. @Alvin

Comment: I don't think I can do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instance of `User` to receive what are commonly referred to as *mixins* from `Player` (which is JavaScript's term for ad-hoc interfaces), you could do the following, **which I don't recommend**:

```js
function User(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
}

User.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return this.name + ' says hello.';
}

User.prototype.becomePlayer = function() {
  Object.assign(this, Player.prototype);
  Player.call(this);
  
  return this;
}

function Player() {
  this.chances = 3;
}

Player.prototype.run = function() {
  return this.name + ' is running.';
}

var user = new User({ name: 'Jacques' });

console.log(user.sayHello());
user.becomePlayer();
console.log(user.run());
```

If you want a **recommended approach**, just make `Player` extend `User` and construct an instance of `Player` to begin with, like this:

```js
function User(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
}

User.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return this.name + ' says hello.';
}

function Player(data) {
  User.call(this, data);

  this.chances = 3;
}

Player.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype);
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;

Player.prototype.run = function() {
  return this.name + ' is running.';
}

var user = new Player({ name: 'Jacques' });

console.log(user.sayHello());
console.log(user.run());
```

Comment: Hello @Patrick Roberts, do you think it's possible to extend from another file ? like player.js ?

Comment: @BryanWesley of course. Just put `var User = require('./user')` at the top of `player.js` if it's in the same directory as `user.js`.

Answer (score -1):

this could be a possible solution to you, but not 100% fit to your situation.

```js
function User(data){
  this.name = data.name;
}

User.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  this.name+' says hello.';
}

function Player(user){
  this.chances = 3;
}

var run = function(){
   console.log(this.name + ' is running.');
}

User.prototype.becomePlayer = function() {
  return Object.assign(User.prototype, {run});
}

//console.log(Player.prototype.run);
var tom = new User({name: "Tom"});
tom.becomePlayer();
tom.run();
```

Comment: This is an incorrect usage of `Object.assign()`. When any instance invokes `becomePlayer()`, _all_ instances will obtain the `run()` method, because it modifies `User.prototype`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts im glad to know, thanks. could there any way achieving the purpose by implementing assign() in the issue?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts why I cant use 'User.prototype.becomePlayer = function() {
  return Object.assign(this.prototype, {run});
}' in a prototype function

Comment: Because `this.prototype` doesn't refer to anything